# Detemine the previous page (i.e. referrer) in jQTouch

Tags: jquery, history, jqtouch, referrer

I am trying to determine the previous page (e.g. the referrer) in order to decide whether to display the back button.

I tried to check for `$('.current').data('referrer')`, but it is not always set. In fact, it is often not set. `history.previous` and `document.referrer` do not seem to be set, either.

Could someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#referrer, it is not always available

Comment: I thought jQTouch would somehow manage referrer, as the whole application is essentially in the one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to go down this path, but the only viable solution I can find is the internal variable (i.e. `hist`) that jQTouch keeps the browsing history. So, I made the following changes to jqouth.js (revision 146):

around line 256, just before the private functions section, insert:

```
function getHistory() { return hist; }
```

around line 625, just before `submitForm: submitForm`, insert:

```
getHistory: getHistory,
```

Then I can look at the browsing history with something like:

```
var previousPageID = jQT.getHistory()[1].id;
```

One caveat is, care should be taken not to accidentally maniplulate the history object.

**EDIT**:

The author has exposed the internal history object since [the version on 14 October 2010](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/blob/f13289063ff4c99ebb5fb7af3a298902464b5820/jqtouch/jqtouch.js), so it can be directly accessed, i.e. `jQT.hist`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling on the same problem using referrer, but I did not get that.
I came up with the following solution that does not force me to modify the jqtouch.js

```
$('body>div').bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, data) {
  if(data.direction === 'out') {
    alert('referrer is : ' + e.currentTarget.id);
  }
});
```

the $('body>div') selector should select all the div that are direct child of the body, which in jqtouch are all the pages definitions.
I found the name of the origin page in the event returned by pageAnimationStart in currentTargetId.

Would appreciate if somebody would tell me if I can be even more restrictive with the selector and if there is also a way of getting the current page.

Comment: I actually think you might need to relax the selector, rather than restrain it: each page does not have to be a <div>; it can be, say, a <form> or other tags. So, `body>*` may actually be more appropriate?

Comment: +1 for it being a good suggestion if I just want the previous page. Thanks!

Comment: Was under the impression that for jQTouch to function properly every page had to be in it's own <div>, that's what tell tQTouch where a page start and finish.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I can't comment, so this is with respect to William's answer of modifying the jqtouch.js.

I think I'll be easier to simply put:

```
hist: hist,
```

Where

```
getHistory: getHistory,
```

is to be placed.

And then there's no need to add the function. Just remember that you're accessing the history itself and not a function, so no need for the rounded brackets.

Then again, this really only applies to older versions of jqtouch.