# JQTouch - Navigate forward without adding page to history

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

How can you navigate to a page without adding it to JQTouches internal history stack?

I have something like:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
<div id="section2"></div>
<div id="section3"></div>
```

and using javascript I navigate from #section1 to #section2 using:

```
jQT.goTo($('#section2'), 'slide'); //with history tracking
```

and then to #section3:

```
jQT.goTo($('#section3'), 'slide'); //want this to be without history tracking
```

So if I had a back button on #section3 and clicked it, it would take me back to #section1 because #section2 would not have been added to the history stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to this. One is, if you know which page you want to go back to, you could simply use the public function like:

```
jQT.goBack('#section1');
```

You can read more about jQT's public objects [here](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/PublicObject).

If you want more control over the history, you might consider tweaking the jQT library so you can access the internal history object. I [had to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499437/detemine-the-previous-page-i-e-referrer-in-jqtouch) to look at the previous page in history.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.
I just added this code, and found my back button no longer worked.

after further investigation, no history was captured.

```
jQT.goTo('#accounts', 'flip');
```